# Combining Eigen's .transpose() and other operations

Tags: c++, eigen3

I was reading [libigl](https://libigl.github.io/)'s documentation, when I opened their [MATLAB to libigl+Eigen conversion table](https://libigl.github.io/matlab-to-eigen.html). There (17th row, or the first red colored row), it stands:

> Do not attempt to combine `.transpose()` in expression like this:
>
> `C = A + B.transpose();`

Instead, they do:

```
SparseMatrixType BT = B.transpose();
SparseMatrixType C = A+BT;
```

Why is that? I could not find anything about it in `Eigen`'s docs.

In my code I have something like:

```
class Point {
public:
    Point() : rot_matrix(Eigen::Matrix3d::Identity()), cm_set(Eigen::Vector3d::Zero()) {}
    const Eigen::Matrix3d & rot_matrix() const { return rot_matrix; }
    const Eigen::Matrix3d & cm_set() const { return cm_set; }
private:
    Eigen::Matrix3d rot_matrix;
    Eigen::Vector3d cm_set;
};


auto other = Point();
const Vector3d point = other.rot_matrix().transpose()*other_cm + other.cm_set();
```

Can that lead to program errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1DenseBase.html#ac8952c19644a4ac7e41bea45c19b909c) docs, the only limitation on `transpose()` is

```
m = m.transpose();
```

Therefore

```
MatrixType res = A + B.transpose();
```

is legal